# Testing random salt method

Tags: java, unit-testing, random, junit, salt

I'm trying to figure out how can I test this method with JUnit. This method creates a random salt of length = x

```
public static String getSalt(int length) {
    StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        returnValue.append(ALPHABET.charAt(SECURE.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
    }
    return new String(returnValue);
}
```

I can test if the length of the output is according to the integer I feed the method with but what I am wondering is how do I test the randomness or is that maybe something that I do not need to do?

Comment: you can test if the regex matches to produced String

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test the randomness or even if this is a requirement, it should be out of scope (its complexity is much greater that the actual method being tested).

What you can test is, indeed, if the length is correct and just test for randomness of two calls of this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if the produces `String` matches the regex of alphabetic with length = X below a snippet you can use or inspire of it :

```
Assert.assertTrue(producedString.matches("^[A-Za-z]{X}$")
```

The `regex` is `^[A-Za-z]{X}$` with X is the length of String

Answer (score 2):

If you mocked whatever `SECURE` is, something like this would be possible to test:

```
public static String getSalt(Secure secure, int length) {
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            returnValue.append(ALPHABET.charAt(secure.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
        }
        return new String(returnValue);
    }
```

then:

```
@Mock 
Secure secure;

@Test
public void testSalt() {
    // arrange
    when(secure.nextInt(any()).thenReturn(0);

    // act
    String salted = getSalt(secure, 3);

    // assert
    assertEquals(salted, "AAA");
}
```

This just goes to show how [static is death to testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) and how following good OOP practice like passing in dependencies through constructors can help test.